# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: productResourceProvider <- productResource <- ProductListCtrl

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

[image: You can view the error here]

I don't know what the error is as I am pretty new to angularjs. I am trying to consume webapi service using the following code.

The app.js file:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = angular.module("productManagement",
                            ["common.services"]);

}());
```

productListCtrl.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("productManagement")
        .controller("ProductListCtrl",
                     ["productResource" ,ProductListCtrl]);

    function ProductListCtrl(productResource) {
        var vm = this;

        productResource.query(function (data) {
            vm.products = data;
        });
    }
}());
```

commonservices.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("common.services", ["ngResource"])
    .constant("appSettings", {
        serverPath: "http://localhost:55755/"
    });
}());
```

productResource.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("common.services").
    factory("productResource", ["$resource",
        "appSettings",
        productResource])

    function productResource($resource, appSettings) {
        return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/products/:id"); 
    }
});
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Acme Product Management</title>

    <!-- Style sheets -->
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body ng-app="productManagement">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="navbar-brand">Acme Product Management</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div ng-include="'app/products/productListView.html'"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Library Scripts -->
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <!-- Application Script -->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script src="Common/common.services.js"></script>
    <script src="Common/productResource.js"></script> 
    <!-- Product Controllers -->
    <script src="app/products/productListCtrl.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you included all in html file ,looks like you miss factory file in html

Comment: can you show the order that these scripts are loaded in your HTML document?

Comment: I have added the index.html file please take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not executing the anonymous function block that you have written for `productResource.js`, which is preventing the `productResourceProvider` from being registered:

Change this:

**productResource.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("common.services").
    factory("productResource", ["$resource",
        "appSettings",
        productResource])

    function productResource($resource, appSettings) {
        return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/products/:id"); 
    }
}); // <-- Problem lies here.
```

Change to:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("common.services").
    factory("productResource", ["$resource",
        "appSettings",
        productResource])

    function productResource($resource, appSettings) {
        return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/products/:id"); 
    }
}());  // <-- Execute the function block.
```

Answer (score -1):

Correct your order of JS file.

```
<script src="app/products/productListCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="Common/productResource.js"></script> 
<script src="Common/common.services.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
```